# Composer not composing - saying file not found

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-4

I'm using the excellent `phpwkhtmltopdf` library and want to update to latest version and for this I need to use composer.

File structure:

```
vendor
  --mikehaertl
    --php-shellcommand
    --php-tmpfile
  autoload.php
```

Composer.json file:

```
{
"name": "mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf",
"description": "A slim PHP wrapper around wkhtmltopdf with an easy to use and clean OOP interface",
"keywords": ["pdf", "wkhtmltopdf", "wkhtmltoimage" ],
"homepage": "http://mikehaertl.github.com/phpwkhtmltopdf/",
"type": "library",
"license": "MIT",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "Michael Haertl",
        "email": "haertl.mike@gmail.com"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.0.0",
    "mikehaertl/php-tmpfile": "1.0.*",
    "mikehaertl/php-shellcommand": "1.0.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "mikehaertl\\wkhtmlto\\": "src/"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.0.x-dev"
    }
}
}
```

I'm trying to use the library like this:

```
require '/home/bookmark/vendor/autoload.php';
use mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf;
...
$pdf = new Pdf('http://anysite.com'); <-- error points to this line
```

The problem is I get the error:

**Fatal error:  Class 'mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf' not found in /home/bookmark/public_html/ajax/action.php on line 132**

This is my first time using composer, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In the composer.json, I think you can remove the autoload and add the the library in the require section. On easy way is to run the command composer require mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf

Comment: and you can remove the other required lib, branch alias, add change the name, description etc. to your own profile. You are using the composer.json from the phpwkhtmltopdf library. You should create your own.

Comment: This is completely new to me, can you expand on that?

Comment: Assuming you have composer installed (otherwise I guess you have composr.phar) just delete the composer.json and run "composer require mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf". It will generate all you need.

Comment: I already tried that and get `-bash: composer: command not found` but composer is definitely installed hence how I have the `vendor` directory, I also have `.composer` directory - do i need to be in a particular directory to run that?

Comment: Do you have a composer.phar or composer file in the root of your project directory ?
If so run the command from there. In worth case, re-install it global and try the command again. to install composer: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/composer.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using some package, you must not copy their `composer.json` file - that won't work.

The best thing would be to run `composer init` once to create an initial `composer.json` file for your project, and `composer require mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf:~2.0` to add this package you want to work with.

After that, it should work.

Comment: Thanks, that info is just not anywhere, they need to seriously look at their docs I think

Comment: Now the question is: Who is "they", and which docs are you referring to. Because the installation procedure for "phpwkhtmltopdf" is this short one-liner: `composer require mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf`. And the Composer documentation isn't bloated either: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#declaring-dependencies